# Why should I keep the default _id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, primary-key, composite-primary-key, objectid

I'm a beginner to MongoDB.

I wonder if there are any trade-offs between using the default _id(object id) and _id(combination of few columns that acts as a primary key) in terms of performance / memory etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. `_id` is binary, and thus takes up less space.
2. ObjectIds also have the sorting factor
   they will end up being in insertion order (or very close), while remaining unique. The sorting can be good for some things, but unwanted for others (like shard keys).
3. You can also extract the timestamp (second resolution) from an ObjectId, which can be convenient.

One more link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk/oQYZQxCAKN8J

**default _id i.e Object id is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:**

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

#### So it's unique over collection and it is have by default index.

MongoDB uses B-Tree indexes. Searching for a particular value in a B-Tree has O(log n) complexity in the average and worst case, which can be considered reasonably fast (i.e. a binary search). It is not constant complexity = O(1) though, so you still might have some slowdown effects if the index size grows larger than available RAM.

MongoDB tries to keep the indexes in RAM, and every IO needed to look up an index on disk will slow down your query considerably.

So already if there is indexed primary columns is maintained and that index is on disk, then why we need an additional primary indexed key. Though you can create your unique constraints if required.

**Update:**
You may not create compound indexes that have hashed index fields. You will receive an error if you attempt to create a compound index that includes a hashed index. Hashed index is used for sharding (sharding is useful when you have high amounts of data in same collection).

If you have millions of records then you should use sharding of collection. You can make composite key if you want to add unique constraint, and specify order for faster search.

```
db.products.createIndex( { "price": 1, "stock": -1 } ).
```

So products with higher stock and less price will be searched faster.

**So it is highly dependent on what data you want to search. By having additional composite key with object Id, will be useful, if it is made on correct properties.**

Comment: Thanks. But what my primary key is made up of two or more columns and I have millions of records to be retrieved and processed every time. Does having a compound primary key affects the performance in any way? Or should I stick to the default object id itself?

Comment: If you have millions of records then you should use sharding of collection. You can make composite key if you want to add unique constraint, and specify order for faster search. `db.products.createIndex( { "price": 1, "stock": -1 } )`. So products with higher stock and less price will be searched faster.

Comment: If you want to check the performance of the compound key vs default object id, append explain() function to your query.